# change button visibility based on selected employees

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My button btnAction always disappears after first combobox cb1 textchanged event and never appears. I want this button visible when emp and tmp are different, and invisible when they aren't.

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    public int? SalaryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Salary Salary { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(Employee le, Employee re)
    {
        if (le.FirstName != re.FirstName)
            return false;
        if (le.LastName != re.LastName)
            return false;
        if (le.Phone != re.Phone)
            return false;
        if (le.SalaryId != re.SalaryId)
            return false;
        if (le.Salary != re.Salary)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Employee le, Employee re)
    {
        if (le.FirstName == re.FirstName)
            return false;
        if (le.LastName == re.LastName)
            return false;
        if (le.Phone == re.Phone)
            return false;
        if (le.SalaryId == re.SalaryId)
            return false;
        if (le.Salary == re.Salary)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

public class Salary
{
    [Key]
    public int SalaryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    public static bool operator ==(Salary ls, Salary rs)
    {
        if (!ls.Name.Equals(rs.Name))
            return false;
        if (ls.Amount != rs.Amount)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Salary ls, Salary rs)
    {
        if (ls.Name.Equals(rs.Name))
            return false;
        if (ls.Amount == rs.Amount)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

and method that is called when combobox cb1 changes

```
public void cb1_OnTextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dataType == 1)
    {
        Employee tmp;
        tmp = emp/*es*/;
        tmp.FirstName = cb1.Text;
        if (tmp == emp/*es*/)
            this.btnAction.Visible = false;
        if (tmp != emp/*es*/)
            this.btnAction.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
public void cb1_OnTextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dataType == 1)
    {
       this.btnAction.Visible = !(cb1.Text == emp.FirstName)
    }
}
```

but I think you should revise your `!=` operator.  assume two employee (emp1, emp2) that just have same first name.

both `emp1 == emp2` , `emp1 != emp2` is false!

Answer (score 0):

You never created a new Employee.

```
tmp = emp/*es*/;
```

This line gives you another variable called `tmp` referencing *the same employee* as `emp`.

```
tmp.FirstName = cb1.Text;
```

This line changed the only employees first name you ever had. So in the end, you are comparing `emp` with itself. If your operators are implemented correctly, that should always yield true.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same. Because both `temp` and `emp` refer to the same object, if any of them make any changes in their values. Both will have those changes.

You should do something like this:

```
if(cb1.Text == emp.FirstName)
    this.btnAction.Visible = false;
else
    this.btnAction.Visible = true;
```